# Создание API при написании плагина jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript, ооп, плагин

Добрый день.
Как можно реализовать хранение методов плагина в DOM объекте?

Видел реализацию плагина, где можно было получить доступ к методам плагина через DOM элемент:

```
var test = $('div').testPlugin();
test.method();
$('div').method();
```

Такое возможно? И если возможно, то как этого добиться?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Читали](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/)? Плагин добавляет прототипу jQuery новые методы. В вашем примере — "`method()`".

Конструкция вида `$('div')` [возвращает объект jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/), у которого, разумеется, присутствуют добавленные прототипу методы плагина.

Comment: Человек не то хотел, как я понял. В общем суть такая: 

У нас есть плагин `testPlugin()`, который возвращает определенный метод, допустим этот метод называется `method()`.

ТС хочет, чтобы возвращаемый метод стал методом объекта jQuery при определенных селекторах, что считаю, по дефолту невозможно.

Comment: Мне по-прежнему хочеться видеть простейший вариант толкования вопроса ТС : )